# Convert std::string to std::wstring and vise versa

Tags: c++, string

I've been reading quite a lot about how to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` but all the answers I have found was very old. I tried using `std::codecvt` to convert but it gives a warning stating that it is deprecated and use `WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()` using the `Windows.h` header file. But then, I'm not sure if I can make it work on other platforms.

Is there a way to convert `std::string` to `std::wstring` and vise versa in *modern* C++?

Comment: This is one of the major weakness in the C++ library. It's more convenient to use other third party libraries.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "*convert between std::string and std::wstring*"? You want to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16LE? Or something else?

Comment: @rustyx What I mean is, to convert a string in `std::string` to `std::wstring` and from `std::wstring` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::wstring` holds `wchar_t` elements, and `wchar_t` is a different size across platforms (2 bytes on Windows, 4 bytes elsewhere), and as such `std::wstring` uses different encodings across platforms (UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 elsewhere). Just as `std::string` can hold different 8bit encodings (UTF-8, ISO-8859-x, Windows-125x, etc).

So, you are not asking how to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring` themselves, but how to convert between different encodings. And the fact is, C++ simply doesn’t support that natively. C++11 tried to address that with `std::codecvt` and `std::wstring_convert`, but they are limited, and as you have noted have since been deprecated in C++17, with no replacement is sight.

So, you best options is to use 3rd party cross-platform libraries, such as ICU, ICONV, etc.